# Azure Pipeline - script to test URL in on premise environment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm doing an stage in azure pipeline after deploying.
I would like to run a script to get the HTTP 200 return from the application that was deployed.

Deploy runs on servers on premise. And the URL I want to test is only accessible on the internal network. There are some smoke web tests on the marketplace, but they only test URLs that are accessible on the internet.

it is possible to run a script as below, being executed by the installed onpremise agent.
The agent on the internal network would be able to access the URL to be tested

```
result=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w “%{http_code}” www.bing.com/)

if [ “$result” == “200” ]
then
echo “OK”
else
echo $result
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Can I ask - why do you think it might *not* work? If an agent has enough access on your internal network to deploy an application, it can certainly have enough access to load the application's webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a private build pool (on-premise agents registered on an Azure Devops Pool) lets call them **build pool servers** and those servers have network connectivity with your servers on which you perform your deployment, then you can create a powershell or bash script depending on your operating system to check the curl result.

The actual powershell script will run on your build agent (the machine which has network connectivity with your deployment servers)

Powershell example:

```
$result = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.google.com).StatusCode; 
Write-Host $result
```

If webpage exist, then you will get a 200 result else another HTTP code.

Comment: Thanks GeralexGR, I only have deploy agents, I will try to run the powershell via deploy. Thanks.